# Android Fragment transition overlapping

Tags: android

I am a seasonal android developer. Trying to switch fragments from navigation drawer. Here is my method:

```
@Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fm= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(position==R.id.nav_profile)
        {
            Fragment pf= new ProfileFragment();
            fm.replace(R.id.fragmentTrick, pf);
            fm.addToBackStack(null);
            fm.commit();
        } else if(position==R.id.nav_home){
            Fragment pf= new TricksFragment();
            fm.replace(R.id.fragmentTrick, pf);
            fm.addToBackStack(null);
            fm.commit();
        }


    }
```

Transition works fine with above code but my profile fragment overlaps my other fragment. Here is the XML file for Profile fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:hint="First Name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Tricks fragment is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/viewRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main activity XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/layoutDrawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTrick"
        class="com.i3techs.mtricks.TricksFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I couldn't find the similar issue on stack overflow. I might be doing something wrong. Please advise.

Comment: `Fragment`s declared in `<fragment>` elements in the layout cannot be removed dynamically. Your transactions are just adding those `Fragment`s on top of that `TricksFragment`. Get rid of the `<fragment>`, and dynamically transact your `Fragment`s in the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try.

Comment: Thanks, It's working now.